# Overlapping Polygons in PostGIS/GeoServer

Tags: gis, polygon, postgis, overlap, geoserver

I have a set of polygons stored in PostGIS and served by GeoServer WMS. The problem is the polygons have overlap, which makes the labels misplaced in different zoom levels.
To solve the problem, I tried to intersect the polygons recursively and add up the attributes of the polygons that share a space. I came across this solution:  [PostGIS recursive intersection between polygons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15620529/postgis-recursive-intersection-between-polygons). It works perfectly with the test dataset but does not work with my data. In my own dataset I tried to do the same but with a column called "hrv".

Here is a link to [my data (shapefile)](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/8ewcn4rkf57z2p4/AAA0CVCmR_I9-ns_JCa8isMYa?dl=0)

It is much appreciated if anyone has an idea on either how to make that solution working on my data or configuring GeoServer to handle the labeling.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can [check this example](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-cookbook/polygons.html#polygon-with-styled-label) from the Geoserver v2.6 guide. It shows the sld to put the labels in the center of the polygon and wrap it with a fixed size to split the labels in multiple lines.

It it does not work try to paste a screenshot of your problem and the sld that you are using to give a more accurate answer.